# Multiple backgrounds with different background-repeats for the x and y directions

Tags: css

I current have a class with 3 different background-images, and I want to be able to use [multiple backgrounds](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_multiple_backgrounds) as well as the [two-value syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-repeat#Syntax) for `background-repeat` that lets you specify different x and y repeat values.

The following css doesn't work:

```
background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat, no-repeat round, no-repeat no-repeat;
```

Firefox gives the warning

> Expected end of value but found 'round'.  Error in parsing value for 'background-repeat'.  Declaration dropped.

However using the single-value syntax does work with multiple images:

`background-repeat: no-repeat, round, no-repeat;`

And the two-value syntax does work with single images:

`background-repeat: no-repeat round`

Am I doing CSS wrong or is combining these two features not possible with CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox (as well as Chrome/Safari) does not support the `round` keyword, which is why it errors out. You can see this in the compatibility table in the article you link to. None of your given declarations should work as they all have `round` somewhere in the value.

The two-value syntax works with multiple backgrounds just fine.

Comment: Oh so there's actually no reason (yet) to use the two-value syntax because there are one-value equivalents of all combinations of `no-repeat` and `repeat`. Thanks!

Comment: @Miguel: Yep, at least for now.